# How to set center vertical alignment of MergeCell by OpenXml with C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

How to set center vertical alignment of MergeCell by OpenXml with C#, below code snippet is my MergeCell implementation in C#

```
mergeCells.Append(new MergeCell() { Reference = new StringValue("A2:A4") });

worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());
```

But the text value in merged cell was moved to right corner, how can I move to center of merged cell?

[output cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwHAk.png)

Thank you in advance